# virtual keyboard hides only one edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

So I have 5 `EditText`'s and the virtual `soft keyboard` work almost fine with the `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but the 4th `EditText` element is hidden (by the keyboard) when I hit 'next' to go to the next edit text.

*only when I start writing the UI gets up and I can see the `EditText`

**XML Code:** (The problematic element is the `EditText` with 'email' id.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/user_container"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <TextView
            android:text="Register"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/logo_full"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="3">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/keycode_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/keycodelogo"
                android:layout_width="22.0dp"
                android:layout_height="22.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/keycode_lable"
                android:tint="#d9e5f3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/keycode"
                android:layout_width="197.0dp"
                android:layout_height="35.5dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/keycode_lable"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="קוד רישום"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColorHint="#d9e5f3"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/user_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/userlogo"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/user_lable"
                android:tint="#d9e5f3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/user"
                android:layout_width="197.0dp"
                android:layout_height="35.5dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_lable"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColorHint="#d9e5f3"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/pass" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pass_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/passlogo"
                android:layout_width="22.0dp"
                android:layout_height="22.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/pass_lable"
                android:tint="#d9e5f3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pass"
                android:layout_width="197.0dp"
                android:layout_height="35.5dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pass_lable"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:textColorHint="#d9e5f3"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                                                                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/maillogo"
                android:layout_width="22.0dp"
                android:layout_height="22.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/email_lable"
                android:tint="#d9e5f3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="197.0dp"
                android:layout_height="35.5dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/email_lable"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:textColorHint="#d9e5f3"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                                                                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phone_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/mobilelogo"
                android:layout_width="22.0dp"
                android:layout_height="22.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/phone_lable"
                android:tint="#d9e5f3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="197.0dp"
                android:layout_height="35.5dp"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/phone_lable"
                android:hint="@string/phone_num"
                                                                android:gravity="end"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textColorHint="#d9e5f3"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_container"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:text="Register"
                android:layout_width="132.0dp"
                android:layout_height="42.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:background="@drawable/loginbutton"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**What can cause this?**

tl;dr `softKeyboard` hides only 1 element out of five, and its the one with 'email' id.

Comment: Put your whole layout inside nested scroll view and use adjust resize property in side android manifest . may be can solve your problem

Comment: @JayThummar Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Jay_Thummar I solved the problem.

wrapping the layout with `ScrollView` and changing the `SoftInputMode` to `AdjustResize` it worked.